# How can I hide a tool from command window under category

Tags: arcobjects, add-in, tools

I have created a tool, a button and a dockable window under one project. To open/close the dockable window, button is used. For some specific work, by clicking some specific button from dockable window, I have activated the tool. So, basically the tool is used from the dockable window. So, the tool shouldn't visible to the user in the command window under the category.

I couldn't find any document to hide the tool. Is there any process that can help me to hide the tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the Config.esriaddinx just remove the text within the categories tag and re-build your solution:

e.g.

```
category=""
```

This should eliminate it from being listed in commands within the Add-Inn category.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `category=""` to an empty string will place your command or tool in the **Misc.** category under Customize>Commands thus not really hiding it.

If extending ArcObjects, to fully hide a custom menu/tool/command you need to remove or comment out the `COM Registration Function(s)` region of the tool or command.  This will prevent it from displaying in the user interface and still allow you to programmatically call the command by it's UID.  You can still add it to a toolbar or menu but only by coding it to be there.